# When httrack downloads the site, it says forbidden or access denied error code: 1020

Tags: web-scraping, web, copy, httrack

when I try to download this site https://www.classcentral.com/ with httrack, I get either forbidden or acces denied error code 1020 error in the index.html file. how can i solve this

Tried all the programs I could find but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

HTTrack has been out for a long time. Most sites has protection specifically against it or they use a 3rd party software (like CloudFlare) which protects against bot activities. You may try to change setting so that CloudFlare doesn't recognise it as a bot, but I doubt it will work.